# Project a 3D surface(generated by plot_trisurf) to xy plane and plot the outline in 2D

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a set of point cloud with this format:

```
x = [1.2, 1.3, .....]
y = [2.1, 1.2, .....]
z = [0.5, 0.8, .....]
```

And I use `plot_trisurf` to plot(by Delauney triangulation) a 3D surface that "represents" the point cloud.

My question is: is there a quick/decent method to project the surface generated by `plot_trisurf` to xy plane and only plot the outline of the projection as a 2D plot?

For example, suppose all my points in the point cloud are on a sphere surface, then `plot_trisurf` will plot a (not-that-perfect) sphere for me. Then my target is to "project" this sphere to xy plane and then draw its outline as **2D** plot(which is a circle).

Edit:

Kindly note that this **2D**
 plot is a 2D curve(possibly closed curve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an arbitrary surface, the projection is trivial, simply set all the `z` values to `0`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')

n=100
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, n)
y = np.sin(x)+np.cos(x)
z = y*y

ax1.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
ax1.set_title(r"$z=y^2$")
ax2.plot_trisurf(x, y, np.zeros_like(x))
ax2.set_title(r"$z=0$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

For a known regular surface, like a sphere, you can simply take the [maximum cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(geometry)) with respect to a given direction. I.e. for a circle centered on the origin take only the `x` and `y` pairs for which `z==0` or `abs(z) < threshold`, or for which the `z` along the vertical line perpendicular to the `yx` plane is minimized. This approach only works if the sphere has not already been 'flattened'. As an example using the latter method (but using `plot_surface` since I already have code for it and using the same preamble from above),

```py
n = 100
r = 5
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, n)
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, n)
x = r * np.outer(np.cos(theta), np.sin(phi))
y = r * np.outer(np.sin(theta), np.sin(phi))
z = r * np.outer(np.ones_like(theta), np.cos(phi))

x_out = list()
y_out = list()
for t in theta:
    zm = r
    idx = 0
    for ii in range(len(phi)):
        if abs(r * np.cos(phi[ii])) < zm:
            zm = r * np.cos(phi[ii])
            idx = ii
    x_out.append(r * np.cos(t) * np.sin(phi[idx]))
    y_out.append(r * np.sin(t) * np.sin(phi[idx]))

ax1.plot_surface(x, y, z)
ax1.set_title("Sphere")
ax2.plot(x_out, y_out, np.zeros_like(x_out), linestyle='-')
ax2.set_title("Maximum Cross Section Outline")
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are irregular surfaces for which this will work as well, but may require interpolation if the polar distribution of points is not uniform. A more robust (but computationally intensive way) to do this is to create a [`cascaded_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union) using [`shapely`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). To generalize this approach, some filtering must be done to remove what `shapely` considers invalid polygons, i.e. those which have a self intersection. You can do this with the following

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams
from math import cos, sin
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from shapely import geometry
from matplotlib import patches

n=100
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2, n)
r = np.linspace(0, 1.0, n)

x = r * np.cos(t)
y = r * np.sin(t)

z = np.sin(-x*y)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')

polygons = list()
# Create a set of valid polygons spanning every combination of
# four xy pairs
for k in range(1, len(x)):
    for j in range(1, len(x)):
        try:
            polygons.append(geometry.Polygon([(x[k], y[k]), (x[k-1], y[k-1]), 
                                              (x[j], y[j]), (x[j-1], y[j-1])]))
        except (ValueError, Exception):
            pass

# Check for self intersection while building up the cascaded union
union = geometry.Polygon([])
for polygon in polygons:
    try:
        union = cascaded_union([polygon, union])
    except ValueError:
        pass

xp, yp = union.exterior.xy

ax1.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
ax1.set_title(r"$z=sin(-x*y)$")
ax2.plot_trisurf(x, y, np.zeros_like(x))
ax2.set_title(r"$z=0$")
plt.show()   # Show surface and projection

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 6))
ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(np.stack([xp, yp], 1), alpha=0.6))
ax.plot(xp, yp, '-', linewidth=1.5)
plt.show()   # Show outline
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's really helpful. A quick question: is it possible to draw the outline in 2D format instead of 3D?

Comment: @CodingNow Yes it is, in the example above if the projection `ax2` is not set to 3D and you use `ax2.plot(x_out, y_out)` you will get a subplot in 2D

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm more interested in the first approach since my surface is irregular(my polar distribution of points is not uniform). Is it possible to plot  2D instead of 3D in the first approach? I tried `ax2.plot(x, y)` but I only got a sine wave.

Comment: @CodingNow I’m afraid that will require a more complicated approach.... I will post an edit which includes that approach tomorrow

Comment: @CodingNow Turns out it was even more complicated than I expected, still working on it.....

Answer (score 4):

You could use `trimesh` or a similar module to quickly achieve your goal without reinventing the wheel, as such libraries already implement methods for dealing with meshes.

See below a quick implementation of a projection of a surface onto an arbitrary plane, defined by its normal vector and origin.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import trimesh

mesh = trimesh.load('./teapot.obj')
triangles = mesh.faces
nodes = mesh.vertices

x = nodes[:,0]
y = nodes[:,2]
z = nodes[:,1]

# Section mesh by an arbitrary plane defined by its normal vector and origin
section = mesh.section([1,0,1], [0,0,0])

fig = plt.figure()    
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=triangles, color=(0,1,0,0.3), alpha=0.3)
ax.scatter(section.vertices[:,0], section.vertices[:,2], section.vertices[:,1])

plt.axis([-3, 3, -3, 3])
plt.show()
```

The result is:
[image]

Hope this can be of help!

Comment: This is very elegant, I had not heard of this library